# Unable to use UTC_TIMESTAMP with AS

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a syntax error while using [UTC_TIMESTAMP](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-utc_timestamp-function.php)

Here is my query:

```
select UTC_TIMESTAMP() as utc_timestamp;
```

This is the error I'm getting

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'utc_timestamp' at line 1

What is going on here?
If I just do `SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP()` it works.

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks it worked. I see it now `utc_timestamp` is like a variable too. Can be used without `()`.

Comment: Exactly, I wanted to wrap `utc_timestamp` with ` ` (To show an alternative), but accidently deleted my comment

Comment: Never mind, you can add your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're naming it incorrectly. MySQL thinks `utc_timestamp` is a function call similar to `UTC_TIMESTAMP`.

Use `my_utc_timestamp` and it should work.